# What will happen if i will not store returned value from Array.map?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(){
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   arr.map(function(item, index){
     if(item%2){
      // do something
     } else {
     // do something 
    }
   });
}
```

Suppose if I'll not store the returned value from Array.map, will it going to effect the performance of the application?

Comment: If you don't want the return value from `.map()` why not just use `.forEach()`?

Comment: it is potentially slower than `forEach`, because it generates an array.

Comment: forEach is 70% slower than map

Comment: @AmitKharka What makes you think that?

Comment: Will there be any memory leakage?